# OpenVPN bridge doesn't work outside LAN

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I trying setup OpenVPN server. This is the network:
cable modem, TP-Link router with OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05.1 / LuCI 15.05-149-g0d8bbd2 Release (git-15.363.78009-956be55)
192.168.15.1 router
192.168.15.20 PC with DHCP Static Leases Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Xenial x64 It's my main machine with working samba share
192.168.15.22 virtual machine windows 7 pro sp1 x86 with DHCP Static Leases
192.168.15.254 virtual machine ubuntu server static IP address

I installed and configured OpenVRT on ubuntu server (.15.254) with help this tutorial:
[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN#Configuring_the_Server](http://here)

I open port 1194 on router TCP, UDP tested and working
I installed ddclient with free DNS tested and working
I haven't any iptables rule, empty all 3 chain.

I can connect to the server with OpenVPN GUI from win7 virtual machine from local network. It's working everything ping other machines, connect to samba on PC (.15.20)

Outside of LAN with win7 PC & OpenVPN GUI I can connect to server, I get right IP address 192.168.15.225, I can ping the server 192.168.15.254, I can ping the client from server, and that's it, I can't do anything else. I can't ping other machines 192.168.15.1 (router) 192.168.15.20 (main machine), I can't reach samba share, I can't see other machines under network browsing.

What is the problem and why can't working properly:

under the config files:
interfaces, down.sh, up.sh, server.conf, client.ovpn:

/etc/network/interfaces:

---

```
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.15.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.15.1
    broadcast 192.168.15.255
    dns-nameservers 192.168.15.1 8.8.8.8
    bridge_ports eth0

iface eth0 inet manual
    up ip link set $IFACE up promisc on
    down ip link set $IFACE down promisc off

#virtualbox virtualis gep miatt kell az alabbi 4
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

/etc/openvpn/down.sh:

---

```
#!/bin/sh

BR=$1
DEV=$2

/sbin/brctl delif $BR $DEV
/sbin/ip link set "$DEV" down
```

/etc/openvpn/up.sh:

---

```
#!/bin/sh
BR=$1
DEV=$2
MTU=$3
/sbin/ip link set "$DEV" up promisc on mtu "$MTU"
/sbin/brctl addif $BR $DEV
```

/etc/openvpn/server.conf:

---

```
mode server
tls-server

local 192.168.15.254 ## ip/hostname of server
port 1194 ## default openvpn port
proto udp

#bridging directive
dev tap0
script-security 2 ## allow calling up.sh down.sh
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0 tap0 1500"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0 tap0"

persist-key
persist-tun

#certificates and encryption
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0

cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo

#DHCP Information
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
server-bridge 192.168.15.254 255.255.255.0 192.168.15.225 192.168.15.235
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.15.1"
push "route 192.168.15.1 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
max-clients 10

#log and security
user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

client.ovpn:

---

```
### Client configuration file for OpenVPN

# Specify that this is a client
client

# Bridge device setting
dev tap

# Host name and port for the server (default port is 1194)
# note: replace with the correct values your server set up
remote ***server url*** 1194
proto udp

# Client does not need to bind to a specific local port
nobind

# Keep trying to resolve the host name of OpenVPN server.
## The windows GUI seems to dislike the following rule. 
##You may need to comment it out.
resolv-retry infinite

# Preserve state across restarts
persist-key
persist-tun

# SSL/TLS parameters - files created previously
ca ca.crt
cert pisti.crt
key pisti.key

# Since we specified the tls-auth for server, we need it for the client
# note: 0 = server, 1 = client
tls-auth ta.key 1

# Specify same cipher as server
cipher BF-CBC

# Use compression
comp-lzo

# Log verbosity (to help if there are problems)
verb 3
```

Comment: So your TP-Link is running OpenVpn server and Ubuntu server with Samba share is connected to TP-Link?

Comment: No, It's a typo sorry. "I installed and configured OpenVRT on ubuntu server (.15.254)" => I installed and configured OpenVPN on ubuntu server (.15.254) The server running on VM. I write the router spec. I don't know it has some special firewall or something. Anyway i found the solution, see My next comment.

Answer (score 1):

I continued search and i had a solution. The problem was that the VPN server was a VM, and the VirtualBox setting was not set to promiscuous mode. I changed settings: Seettings -> network -> advanced settings -> set Promiscuous mode to "Allow All". After i did, everything start working fine. Problem solved.